# Centrar el contenido de un div sin alinear el texto Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Buenas tardes, el problema que tengo es el siguiente en esta columna quisiera centrar el contenido del div, pero al utilizar "text-center" el texto se pone centrado también, quisiera que se centre la etiqueta "p" pero que no se altere la alineación del texto que esta posee (es decir que siga alineado a la izquierda)

```
<div class='col-xs-12 col-sh-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4'>
        <h6 class='text-center'>CONTACTO</h6>
        <span class='fui-mail'></span>
        <a href"mailto:idiomas@uba.edu.ve">idiomas@uba.edu.ve</a><br /><br />
        <span class='fui-chat'></span>
        <p id='contacto'>
          <strong class='colored'>Linea Gratuita:</strong> 0500UBA00<br />
          <strong class='colored'>Telefono:</strong> +58 243-265.02.07 / 265.01.97
        </p>
</div>
```

Codigo CSS:

```
footer .colored{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El elemento HTML **P**, ocupa todo el espacio horizontal, por lo que tendrías que cambiarlo para que utilice solo el espacio que requiere con el estilo display: inline-block. Luego colocar la clase text-center a nivel de la columna, y la clase text-left para los elementos que su contenido deben estar alineados a la izquierda.

Ejemplo:

```css
#contacto {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class='col-xs-12 col-sh-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center'>
    <h6 class=''>CONTACTO</h6>
    <span class='fui-mail'></span>
    <a href"mailto:idiomas@uba.edu.ve">idiomas@uba.edu.ve</a><br /><br />
    <span class='fui-chat'></span>
    <p id='contacto' class="text-left" >
      <strong class='colored'>Linea Gratuita:</strong> 0500UBA00<br />
      <strong class='colored'>Telefono:</strong> +58 243-265.02.07 / 265.01.97
    </p>      
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funciona a la perfección, muchísimas gracias

Comment: Excelente! Fue un placer haberte ayudado

Answer (score 0):

acotando a la respuesta de @Javier, puedes usar para centrarlo `text-align:center;`

```css
#contacto {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class='col-xs-12 col-sh-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center'>
    <h6 class=''>CONTACTO</h6>
    <span class='fui-mail'></span>
    <a href"mailto:idiomas@uba.edu.ve">idiomas@uba.edu.ve</a><br /><br />
    <span class='fui-chat'></span>
    <p id='contacto' class="text-left" >
      <strong class='colored'>Linea Gratuita:</strong> 0500UBA00<br />
      <strong class='colored'>Telefono:</strong> +58 243-265.02.07 / 265.01.97
    </p>      
</div>
</div>
```